# Visual Studio 2012 Coded UI testing failed to load package

Tags: c#, testing, user-interface

I have a project which I have to add a coded UI test into.

If I create a test it gives me the following error:

*The following package failed to load: C:\Users\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\W2RG6NJ4.G6O\TMOZA01A.527\ad952cf5\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll. Coded UI Test is now in an inconsistent state. Remove this package and restart Visual Studio to work with Coded UI Test.*

Then it adds the Coded UI test to the project and if I try to record it gives me the same error when I generate the code.

I have seen similar errors, but with the Extension tool, and not the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll

This is the error I get when I try recording.

*The following package failed to load: C:\Users\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\W2RG6NJ4.G6O\TMOZA01A.527\ad952cf5\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll*

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today. I had an existing application made in Visual Studio 2010. Some months ago we updated it to Visual Studio 2012 and now update 1. When we added a coded ui project, we got the message above.
One of the projects in the solution is a mvc 3 project (made in visual studio 2010 and upgraded everytime). That project was the problem for not succesfully creating the coded ui project. We think it is the T4Scaffolding nuget package.

How to fix:
Restart VS 2012 with your project. Unload your MVC project. Add Coded UI test project. Everything must work now correctly. Reload your mvc project. Everything should still work.

Comment: Didn't work for me... The problem showed up after I installed "code first UI test" package, that depends on "T4Scaffolding". I tried to uninstall them and it failed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I don't anything else. It must be something with T4Scaffolding package... We are going to upgrade to MVC 4 (copying all the files to new web application) so we don't have the package anymore.

Comment: We have the same issue, but are using MVC4 and no T4Scaffolding anywhere... Any other suggestions or ways to debug this?

Comment: Did you upgrade your site from MVC 3 to MVC 4? We found that the problem was somewhere between those pieces. Our problem was the T4Scaffolding package. When we created a new MVC 4 project (this was also an upgrade from 4 to .NET 4.5) and copied all the controlers etc. The problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else gets this issue for me it turned out that you have to be running VS 2012 as an administrator. When VS is not loaded as an admin then I get this error. When I start VS using the 'Run as administrator' everything works fine.